# Twisted cubic and schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let the map of graded rings $k[w,x,y,z]\to k[t,s]$ given by $(w,x,y,z)\to (s^3,s^2t,st^2,t^3)$.
How can I prove that this map induces a closed embedding $\mathbb{P}_k^1\to \mathbb{P}_k^3$ which yields an isomorphism of $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ with the twisted cubic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just $3$-uple embedding for $n=1$. This is a classic problem. You can see the proofs for the ideas you want [here](http://dauns.math.tulane.edu/~mcan/CommutativeAlgebra.pdf) starting at Problem 34.

Comment: I mean, just write down the generators for $I(Twisted Cubic)$, right?

Answer (score 4):

Look at it locally on each standard open set. For example, when $w\neq0$, we have (on coordinate rings) $k[x/w,y/w,z/w]\to k[t/s]$ where $x/w\mapsto t/s$, $y/w\mapsto t^2/s^2$ and $z/w\mapsto t^3/s^3$. This map is clearly surjective and so the respective map on affine schemes gives a closed embedding. It is the same story with the other affine patches.

Comment: What about the isomorphism?